# Function support callback and return style at once

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript

I am wondering about implementation of functionality like the following one.

As an input I receive a function, which could be either synchronous:

```
externalFunction = () ->
  return true
```

or asynchronous:

```
externalFunction = (done) ->
  done(true)
```

So, I want to distinguish those types of functions

When I receive a synchronous function, I want to call it and then use its results:

```
result = externalFunction()
doSomething result
```

And when I receive an asynchronous one, I want to wait for its callback first:

```
externalFunction (result) ->
  doSomething result
```

What is the best way to do it?

Right now I'm wondering about something like this:

```
promise(externalFunction(myCallback)).complete (err) -> ...
```

Comment: Please, check my edit of your question.

Comment: Thank you Leonid, just asked on mocha chat (mocha is using same logic) and they said, they are passing it like I did in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

This may be the simple answer, but still hoping for better one.

```
myCallbackAfterFunction = (result) ->
  ...

functions = [...]
for func in functions
  if func.length != 0
    func(myCallbackAfterFunction)
  else
    result = func()
    myCallbackAfterFunction(result)
```

Comment: Am I right that you have an external function and you don't know if it is synchronous or asynchronous, so you want to support both variants?